# Set NSImage.image at runtime with a systemimage under MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, uiimage, nsimage

In the Interfacebuilder, NSImagebutton offers a wide range of system images to pick (see screenshot). I fail to change these images at runtime under MacOS. Under iOS there is UIImage with `UIImage(systemName: "imageName")` but MacOS seems to offer nothing comparable?

[image: system images to chose from]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite similar in macOS for example

```
button.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.touchBarQuickLookTemplateName)
```

Comment: Thanks!
In the Interfacebuilder there are also images name available like "play.fill" or "pause.fill". How would you use these images? I've tried NSImage(named: "play.fill") but this results in a crash

Comment: There is a [new API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/3622472-init) in Big Sur. In Catalina and lower you have to export the images from the SF Symbols app and add them to your asset catalog.